# Autoconf complains of undefined macro, suggests m4_pattern_allow? what's going on?

Tags: autotools, cc

I've done a lot of C and some C++ programming, but never used autotools before (I was doing this so long ago, the tools were not yet available to me).  Anyway, I'm on Xubuntu 20.04, and I'm following a tutorial at https://earthly.dev/blog/autoconf/ and I've created this configure.ac

```
AC_INIT([helloworld], [0.1], [myemail@gmail.com])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

which seems to agree with the tutorial, and I did `aclocal` okay but when I try to do `autoconf` I get

```
configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in "." "./.." "./../.."
```

I have no idea why this comes up, and while I can guess in general, I don't know specifically what those install things are, or why `configure` seems to think I
need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't much care for some of the details of the article you linked.  Generally speaking, one should not run the individual autotools manually (`aclocal`, `autoconf`, *etc*.), and a recommendation to routinely do so undermines the recommender's credibility with me.  Use `autoreconf` instead.  It determines which of the individual autotools to run, and runs them all in the correct order.  Most of the time, that's all you need to do.

For a new or newly autotooled project, however, or if you otherwise get messages such as you report about scripts and tools being missing, add the `--install` option to your `autoreconf` run.  In that case, I tend to also use the `--force` option for good measure, though often it's unnecessary:

```
autoreconf --install --force
```

The `--install` part will ensure that all the helper scripts needed for the Autotools components you are presently using are installed in the project source tree, and the `--force` option will replace any that are already there.

NOTE: If you plan to use [`AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.71/autoconf.html#index-AC_005fCONFIG_005fAUX_005fDIR) in your `configure.ac` then it is convenient to put it in before running `autoreconf --install`, because it affects where the helper scripts will be put.

Comment: Yep, your answer is accepted. That not only worked the first time, it created the "install.sh" file that was the subject of the complaint I was asking for help with.  Now I will go on to do some more stuff, and probably make some more newb mistakes.